# Pegar segunda linha de uma tabela

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-crawler, pupeteer

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação usando node.js e puppeter para pegar dados de uma página web, o problema que tenho e que não estou conseguindo pegar as colunas que quero dentro da linha selecionada, essa é a parte do código que estou tendo dificuldades:

```
 async function buscaFases(frame) {
    return await frame.evaluate(() => {
        let div = document.querySelector('div[id*="conteudo"]');
        let rowns = Array.from(div.children[4].children[0].children);
        let movimentosInfo = rowns.map(row => {
             let data = row.querySelector("tr td:first-child").textContent;
      let descricao = row.querySelector("tr td:first-child + td").textContent;
          return { data, descricao };
        });
        return JSON.stringify(movimentosInfo);
    });
};
```

O código funciona como o esperado até a seleção de linha a linha mas quando vai para pegar a informação da coluna que quero ele retorna null.

Segue o código Completo, com a url para a página e informações pertinentes:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const urlConsulta = "http://www.tre-pr.jus.br/";
const numeroProcessoSeq = "000000889";
const numeroProcessoAno = "2014";
const numeroProcessoDigito = "6160047";

var wait = ms => new Promise((r, j)=> setTimeout(r, ms));

void (async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(urlConsulta);
        await page.select('#acao', 'pesquisarNumUnico');
        await page.evaluate((numeroProcessoSeq, numeroProcessoAno, numeroProcessoDigito) => {
            document.getElementById('numUnicoSequencial').value = numeroProcessoSeq;
            document.getElementById('numUnicoAno').value = numeroProcessoAno;
            document.getElementById('numUnicoOrigem').value = numeroProcessoDigito;
        }, numeroProcessoSeq, numeroProcessoAno, numeroProcessoDigito);

        await page.$eval('form[action*="http://www.tre-pr.jus.br/@@processrequest"]', form => form.submit());

        await page.waitForNavigation();
        var frame = await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'ifr_servicos');
        await frame.click('a[href*="ExibirDadosProcesso"]');
        await page.frames().find(f => f.name() === 'ifr_servicos');
        await wait(10000);
        await frame.click('[name*="todos"]');
        await frame.$eval('[name*="ExibirPartesProcessoZona"]', form => form.submit());
        await wait(10000);
        let string = await buscaFases(frame);
        fs.writeFile("teste.txt", string, function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }); 
        console.log(string);
        await wait(10000);
        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();

async function buscaFases(frame) {
    return await frame.evaluate(() => {
        let div = document.querySelector('div[id*="conteudo"]');
        let rowns = Array.from(div.children[4].children[0].children);
        let movimentosInfo = rowns.map(row => {
            let data = row.querySelector("tr > td + td").textContent;
            let descricao = row.querySelector("tr > td + td + td").textContent;
          return { data, descricao };
        });
        return JSON.stringify(movimentosInfo);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução, o problema é que nem todas as linhas tinham os elementos na ordem que queria então é preciso filtrar somente as linhas que tem o que quero:

```
let movimentosInfo = rowns.filter(row => {
    return row.querySelector("tr td:first-child") && row.querySelector("tr td:first-child + td");
}).map(row => {
    let data = row.querySelector("tr td:first-child").textContent;
    let descricao = row.querySelector("tr td:first-child + td").textContent;
    return { data, descricao };
});
```